# Making mesh of ocean modifier into shape of circle

Tags: ocean-simulation

I've been trying to make my ocean mesh into the shape of a circle. The mesh itself started out as a circle I extruded. But once I put the ocean modifier on it, it makes it into the shape of a square.

I've looked online and tried to play around with how to make the ocean modifier into the shape of a circle. The most prevalent answer was to change the Geometry feature from "Generate" to "Displace". As you will see in my included screenshots, doing this turns my mesh transparent. (Some other ideas I've tried were using the boolean modifier with a circle plane and a sphere)

One comment suggested that I need enough geometry on it, which I went back to my circle plane and I subdivided it yet still got this result.

Any suggestions would be helpful! Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try a boolean modifier after ocean modifier which cuts it out?